# Purchased Used HDD - Error in GSmartControl log interpretation

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, hardware-rec

I purchased some 500GB 2.5in HDD's for use in a homelab I am building.

I am in the process of testing the drives since they were bought used. This particular drive has an error that I cannot decipher. I am curious as to whether someone could lend their expertise to helping me understand this error.

[image: GSmartControl Error Log]

[image: General SMART DATA]

Thank you.

Comment: I see several pre failures in the smart data, the drive is failing and will soon be unusable, scrap it.

Comment: Which values were the indicators? Thanks.

Comment: The ones marked (type) pre failure in you second image.